# Why I can't access NSMutable Array in my method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods

I try to add object to my NSMutable array in my method, but keep getting error. It works, if I add the object in init. It doesn't say that anything is wrong until I try to execute the code.

This is below the #import stuff where I declare two arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *actions1, *actions2;
```

This is in init:

```
actions1 = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Here I try to add 1 to the array:

```
- (void) storeAction:(int) action {
[actions1 addObject:@"1"];
}
```

The same code works in int as I said earlier.

I also would like it to store the int value declared "action", but this didn't seem to work either.

```
[addObject:@"%d", action];
```

Comment: Regarding the [addObject:@"%d", action]; - please elaborate what does it mean "didn't seem to work either".. what's happening ? and BTW - why aren't you storing the int as a NSNumber object ? ([NSNumber numberWithInt:1])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[NSMutableArray array];` is returning an [autoreleased](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease) object, by the time you try to access it, it is most likely deallocated already. Try `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` instead. And than you should urgently check the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i).

Comment: I prefer this to [[NSMutableArray array] retain], plus you explained why your solution works. +1

Comment: Thanks! Will read that tomorrow. Any idea why this won't work? `[addObject:@"%d", action];`

Comment: `addObject` takes a string and doesn't do formatting. You want: `[array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", action]];`

Comment: Thank you. Love peple who are willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code

```
actions1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in your header file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *actions1;
```

Then in the implantation file:

```
@synthesize actions1 = _actions1;
```

Then you can access your array as `self.actions1`.